# Why my css isn't working and shows problems in console

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

Hello my css is not working while it was working 5 minutes ago, i don't really know what's the problem, and i had this error in console :

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for http://localhost:8080/GRH/home/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

[image]
Network shows everything is fine

even the linking and paths are good

Comment: Bootstrap has a dependency on jQuery

Comment: What do you exactly mean ? What’s that ? And how can I solve it ?

Comment: The error message indicates that `jQuery` is undefined as it's trying to access `jQuery.fn` which means that you are probably missing jQuery

Comment: You need to load jquery first before bootstrap.

Comment: I have at least 50 jsp pages so i have to add it to every page ?

Answer (score 1):

Go download [JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) , just choose the compressed script
then before your bootstrap script, just insert jquery script before it

Comment: I have at least 50 jsp pages so i have to add it to every page ?

Comment: ``` 
<!-- jQuery -->
   <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <script src="assets/js/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/imgfix.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/js/mixitup.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/js/accordions.js"></script>
    ```
Here is jquery

Comment: It depends on how your project is arrange. If the bootstrap is applied to all pages then the jquery must be included in all pages too. Usually there is a main/template html that just holds all the script then other pages/routes just use it and have their own code in it

Answer (score -1):

Clear Chrome Cache by "Ctrl+Shift+R", if it doesn't work, open your website in incognito tab. Maybe it will work.

Comment: You can rename the name of CSS file, it will work!